# Laravel Ordering response based on key

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-8

How do I order JSON responses based on key instead of value?

Basically, I successfully return response data

```
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "photo": [
        "tes.png",
        "example.png"
    ],
    "definition": "Editing Video between 1 until 3 minutes",
    "price": 50000,
    "created_at": "2022-04-15T16:40:20.000000Z",
    "updated_at": null,
    "freelancer": {
        "id": 9,
        "highlight_text": "Im a freelancer",
        "highlight_photo": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579353977828-2a4eab540b9a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1974&q=80",
        "created_at": "2022-04-14T16:16:19.000000Z",
        "updated_at": null
    }
}
```

I added new response into field, and the 'freelancer' response add to the bottom of the response instead top of created_at. There is no problem here but I think it is disturb me a little.

Can anyone show me how to ordering it ?

```
$service = Service::find($serviceId)->makeHidden(['freelancer_id']);
        if($service == null){
            return $this -> return_failed(200, "Service didn't exist");
        }
        $service["photo"] = $service["photo"] == null ? null : explode("|", $service["photo"]);
        $service["freelancer"] = Freelancer::find($service["freelancer_id"]);
        return $this -> return_success($service);
```

I am using laravel 8

Comment: So you want `freelancer` before `created_at` ?

Comment: @nice_dev yesss

Answer (score 0):

Use need to add freelancer method to your service model as a relationship and then retrieve it with `->with()` method and then `->toArray()` method makes the array for you.
Also for `$service['php']` you need to ser an accessor in Freelancer model.

```php
Service::query()->whereKey($serviceId)->makeHidden(['freelancer_id'])->with('freelancer')->toArray();


// accessor method in Freelancer model

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;

protected function photo(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(get: function ($value) {
        if($value){
            return explode('|', $value);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: didnt work, it causing error

Comment: @TaufikFadlurahmanFajari what error, be more specific and descriptive in your comments and question plz.